# (Excel) When referencing cells from another worksheet, can I pass the worksheet name as a cell value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that has about ten work sheets, each containing information for each user, and an eleventh sheet as the user interface. On the 11th page (called "Interface"), I have a drop-down box that contains a list of all the user names. When the user selects a name, I'd like cells to autopopulate by linking a cell in Interface to a cell in "username".

For example, let's say the user selects "Ethan" in the drop menu found in A1. A3 would auto-populate with Ethan!A5, So i'm basically looking for a way to enter A1!A5 (Ethan A5) into Interface:A3.

Is this possible?

I'd prefer it I didn't have to use VB to do this. I have little experience with VB as a language, though I have experience using various formulas in excel.

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA for this, it's probably not a programming question :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the text "Ethan!A5", you can use the concatenate function:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,"!A5")
```

Or the short form of this function using `&`:

```
=A1&"!A5"
```

But if you want to get the formula referencing to the cell `Ethan!A5` then you'll have to use the `INDIRECT()` along with either formula I mentioned above:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,"!A5"))
```

Or...

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!A5")
```

In either case, it is usually safer to wrap the sheetname with single quotes (I'll put the shorter formula below):

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A5")
```

Because without the quotes, a worksheet with name `Ethan Schmid` won't work with the formula.

Comment: I know this is an old Q&A - but for anyone wondering, this is the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

`=A1&" A5"` in A3 seems to be what you are asking for.